# A limit with the harmonic series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

How can we prove the following (similar) limits?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} (\ln 2 - \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} - \cdots -\frac{1}{2n + 2}) \to 0. $$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} (\ln 3 - \frac{1}{n+2} - \frac{1}{n+3} - \cdots -\frac{1}{3n + 3}) \to 0. $$

Comment: Hint: Let $a_n \to \alpha$ and $b_n \to \beta$ as $n\to \infty$. Then, $$\frac{a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0}{n}$$ convergence to $\alpha \beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k}\left(\log\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{n+2}-\dots-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)=H_{n}\left(\log\left(2\right)-\sum_{j=n+2}^{2n+2}\frac{1}{j}\right)=H_{n}\left(\log\left(2\right)-H_{2n+2}+H_{n+1}\right)
 $$ where $H_{n}
 $ is the $n
 $-th armonic number. Recalling that $$H_{n}=\log\left(n\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
 $$ as $n\rightarrow\infty
 $ we have $$H_{n}\left(\log\left(2\right)-H_{2n+2}+H_{n+1}\right)=\left(\log\left(n\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\left(\log\left(2\right)-\log\left(2n+2\right)+\log\left(n+1\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=
 $$ $$=\left(\log\left(n\right)+\gamma+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=O\left(\frac{\log\left(n\right)}{n}\right)
 $$ then your claim. The other case is similar. In fact you will get $$\left(\log\left(3\right)-\log\left(3n+3\right)+\log\left(n+1\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\left(\log\left(\frac{3n+3}{3n+3}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
 $$

Comment: What do you mean by $O$ exactly (I'm only familiar with little $o$ notation for infinitesimals)? Finally, could you add at least a sketch of your work for the other case (to check mine)?

Comment: @mathlearner The notation $f\left(x\right)=O\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ means that exists some $C>0$ such that $\left|f\left(x\right)\right|\leq Cg\left(x\right)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $ x_{0}$ for some $x_{0}$ which can be also infinity.

Comment: So, when you write $O(\frac{1}{n})$ you mean $o(1)$, right?

Comment: @mathlearner Yes, in this case is $o(1)$ in particular.